# how to save data in password protected workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with userform, which saves data to remote master workbook. The latter is password protected - set as read only. I am trying to open the workbook as readwrite by using VBA password, however I'm being prompted for a password anyway. Here is my code, could you please guide me, what is it I'm doing wrong? Please help.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim nr As Long

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jasiek\Desktop\Multiple Test\premote.xlsx", Password:="Bartek")
nr = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

[Application wants to save as copy instead of original file, even though the password is typed in manually:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cjIp.png)
[image]

@Storax Thanks, but the issue still persists. I wrote the code, saved, reopened, copied the code, saved, reopened. After hitting submit I've this:[image]

Any idea why this might be the case?

Thanks

Comment: I think the right parameter is WriteResPassword

Answer (score 1):

Change your Workbook.Open line as follwos
  `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Jasiek\Desktop\Multiple Test\premote.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="Bartek")`